# Modify text input value before POST in Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, post

I'm currently trying to modify a text input's value and add a "v" as a pre-fix before the POST.  This code is correctly changing the value and updating the field (i.e. I can see it add the 'v' after the submit), but if I look at the POST request in the debugger I an see the value does not contain the desired result.  It just has whatever the original input was.  Below is my code, what am I not connecting here?

```
$(document).on("ready", function() {
    $('#stb-form').on("submit", function(e) {
        var value = $('#gitVersionInput').val();
        if (value === "") {
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
        var gitTag = 'v' + value;
        $('#git-version').val(gitTag);
        console.log(gitTag);
        $(".modal").modal('show');
        this.submit();
    });
});
```

Comment: What you have should work. The `submit` event obviously fires before the form submits, and changing the value should be reflected in the posted data etc.

Comment: My thoughts too but that's not the case for some reason.

Comment: `this.submit();` shouldn't be needed. Also note that the original input's value isn't being changed, instead you're changing the value of the `#git-version` input.

Comment: Okay, so how does one correctly change the original value then? Kind of why this question exists, unsure what's up with all the down votes.

Comment: I think what Kevin meant, was that `#gitVersionInput` is not the same element as `#git-version` ?

Answer (score -1):

Try submitting the form using a normal input of type button rather than type submit.

```
<input type="button" id="form-submit" value="Submit">

$('#form-submit').on("click", function(e) {
    var value = $('#gitVersionInput').val();
    if (value === "") {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
    var gitTag = 'v' + value;
    $('#git-version').val(gitTag);
    console.log(gitTag);
    $(".modal").modal('show');
    $('#stb-form').submit();
});
```